# Assigning the variable name to the same variable name

Tags: javascript, variables

On executing

```
var a=b=c=d=e=f=a; 
//no error(a has not initialize before)

var x=y;
//ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

How can the first code just execute as if `a` has already been initialize before.

Comment: first statement is like `var a = undefined; window.b=window.c=window.d=window.e=window.f=a;` in second `y is not defined`

Comment: @rab just post that as an answer. It's the correct one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because of variable hoisting. `var x = EXPR;` is actually converted to this:

```
// beginning of the block (function/file)
var x; // === undefined
// ...
// the actual position of the statement
x = EXPR
```

For your example this means:

```
var a;  // === undefined
a = b = c = d = e = f = a;
```

Note that only `a` is declared using `var` - so you are creating tons of globals which is **always a bad thing**!

Comment: So, if remove `a` at the end of expression this will cause an error, but if not, it will create globals and assign value of `a` to all variables?

Comment: yes, that's correct. if you remove the last `a`, the non-existant `f` will be read and cause an exception because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

Your first statement is like

```
var a = undefined; 
a = window.b = window.c = window.d  = window.e = window.f = a;
```

where a is defined, and others are global scoped . suppose you execute a function .

```
(function(){
  var a=b=c=d=e=f=a; 
  b = 10;
}());
```

the `b` can accessed outside .

in second `var x=y` , `y` is not defined yet

Comment: Minor correction: Accessing a global `x` is not exactly like accessing `window.x`: `window.x` never fails but `x` fails if `x` does not exist at all.